# The view core.views.postcodes didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I want to render a local `json` file I'm loading from a view in Django.

I have this function on my `views.py` file:

```
def postcodes(request):
    data = open('core/stores.json').read() 
    jsonData = json.loads(data)
```

On my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('stores/', views.postcodes, name='postcodes'),
]
```

It throws me this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /stores/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/rest_tails2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 139, in _get_response
"returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
ValueError: The view core.views.postcodes didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

I think this comes from the fact that I'm using `request` as a parameter on my `postcodes` function.

Any ideas on how can I load this json file on my view?

I'm using Django 1.11

Comment: Your `postcodes` view does *not* return something, it should return a `HttpResponse` object.

Comment: Note that all of this is pointless. There is no reason to parse the JSON to Python if all you want to do is to send it to the browser. This is a *static file* and should be handled by the static file serving system, just like your JS and CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here you do not return anything, the function is called, but it does not, as expected, returns a `HttpResonse`.

Based on your view, you probably want to return a [**`JsonResponse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects), so we can return this with:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json

def postcodes(request):
    with open('core/stores.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

If you however do not plan to do any filtering, aggregation, or other processing, you however better move the `stores.json` to a static file, like [@DanielRoseman says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472005/the-view-core-views-postcodes-didnt-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned/53472029#comment93814712_53472005).

Comment: Hi Willem, thank you very much, actually I'll filter this through template view later on, so this is really helpful for me to understand all the process, Thank You very much!